# Retrieve custom attribute LABEL in cart with config.xml

Tags: attributes, cart, ce-1.9.0.1

I have a custom attribute that i need to display in the shopping cart. The attribute is a Dropdown like so:

```
Attribute Code : section
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner : Dropdown
Options:
    ID/VALUE = 67 LABEL = warehouse
    ID/VALUE = 69 LABEL = showroom
    ID/VALUE = 70 LABEL = stockroom
```

To display this i have a custom module with my config.xml like so:

```
<global>
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <section/>
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

And in the cart i can call:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getSection();
```

This returns the ID/VALUE of the attribute (i.e 67) but i want to be able to get the LABEL (i.e warehouse)

I know i can get a label from the id like so:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("section");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText("67");
}
```

But I want to get the label through my module so i can cutout extra databae queries and having to load the product model again. My cart can have upwards of 20+ items per order so using this last approach can slow it down slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper method which loads all attribute options once.
And then return only the option value by it's id.

```
class Some_Helper
{
    protected $attributeOptions = null;

    public function getAttributeLabel($optionValue)
    {
        if ($this->attributeOptions === null) {
            $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'section');
            if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
                $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
            }
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $this->attributeOptions[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return isset($this->attributeOptions[$optionValue]) ? $this->attributeOptions[$optionValue] : '';
    }

}
```